# Pass offset from stack/frame pointer to variable to GCC inline assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

In all flavors of GCC, local variables that don't fit into registers are stored on the stack. For accessing them, one uses constructs like [ESP+n] or [EBP-n], where n might involve an offset within the variable.

When passing such variables to GCC inline assembly as operands, a spare register is used to store the calculated address. Is there a way to designate operands as "the base register of this variable" and/or "the offset of this variable relative to the base register"?

Comment: Do you have sample code that illustrates it? If you are just referencing the variable, the compiler should be clever enough to use the `esp` or `ebp` relative addressing. [My example](http://goo.gl/PnejhF).

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like

`int stackvar;`
...
`asm ("...":"r"(stackvar))`

you force GCC to load stackvar into register. If you add `m` constraint, you don't:

`int stackvar;`
...
`asm ("...":"rm"(stackvar))`

Comment: With "m", in my experience, GCC gives it to assembly as [reg]. You can'd do further offsets from that, as in `movl %eax, [$[var]+8]